# How do I only accept three specific names from a user?

Tags: java

2 month old programmer here.

Trying to create a program which accepts 3 student's marks. Output will be The name, the mark and the grade they achieved.
My question is that I only want the program to accept 3 specific names (e.g Lisa, Lorraine, Susan) and if someone else types in another name, I would like it to display "Invalid"

Also
As you can see, i can only display the students name if the user enters the correct mark. (" Hi Lisa, your mark is " + mark ) So if i type in another name and the same mark, it will display the same output. 
How do i resolve?

CODE:

```
package studentmarks;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentMarks 

{


  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    int mark;
    int passmark = 50;

    String name;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" Enter your name "); //ask user for name
    name = sc.nextLine(); //accept input

    System.out.println("Now please enter your mark");   //ask user to enter mark
    mark = sc.nextInt(); //accept mark


    if (mark == 60) //if mark = 60
    {
        System.out.println(" Hi Lisa, your mark is " + mark ); //output
    }

    if (mark ==12)
    {
        System.out.println("Hi Lorraine, you scored a mark of " + mark);  
    }

    if (mark== 50) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hi susan, you have scored a mark of " + mark);
    }

     if (mark < passmark)
    {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
    }

      if (mark >= passmark)
    {
        System.out.println("PASS");
    }


 }
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: There are a number of things you're not doing here.  But I guess to focus on the specific question being asked, you could compare `name` with your hard-coded names.  But remember to use `.equals()` instead of `==` for strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need a validation step. You're never checking the entered `name` against the values that are valid. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // Initial setup stuff here
    // ...

    System.out.println("Enter your name:"); //ask user for name
    name = sc.nextLine(); //accept input

    boolean validName = validateName(name);
    if(validName)
    {
        System.out.println("Now please enter your mark:"); //ask user to enter mark
        mark = sc.nextInt(); //accept mark

        System.out.println("Hi " + name + ". You scored a " + mark + ".");

        String result = "pass";
        if (mark < passmark)
        {
           result = "fail";
        }
        System.out.println("You " + result + ".");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(name + " is not a valid entry.");
    }
}

public boolean validateName(String name)
{
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Lisa") || name.equalsIgnoreCase("Lorraine") || name.equalsIgnoreCase("Susan")
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is this after the main code?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. This snippet contains your `main()` method as well as an additional helper method. You could copy and paste this inside of your `public class StudentMarks()` in place of the current `main()` and it will work